# Devise AJAX: Instant rollback with no errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to setup Devise in Rails 4 to allow users registration to take place via an AJAX request. I've followed this guide: http://natashatherobot.com/devise-sign-up-ajax-rails/

I've setup the form, but I just get this in the logs when I try to register:

```
Started POST "/users" for 192.168.0.18 at 2013-08-31 00:46:59 -0400
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (3.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "user"=>{"email"=>"wattapop@pop.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}
   (1.7ms)  begin transaction
   (1.4ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 200 OK in 268ms (Views: 3.5ms | ActiveRecord: 12.6ms)
```

I think I've done all the setup correctly, and am totally stumped as to what to do. Any advice would be great!

**EDIT:** The controller is returning two errors: Email can't be blank, and password can't be blank. Not quite sure why...

Comment: put this on create method `Rails.logger.info(@user.errors.inspect)` and you will see error message. Just a guess, I think rollback transaction because password too short.

Comment: Thanks @anonymousxxx - It's throwing errors that email/password can't be blank. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

According to this post:

```
 [rails 3.1, why devise can't build the resource?][1]
```

You're going to want to change your registrations_controller.rb to read:

```
build_resource sign_up_params
```

This fixed it for me.